# Autofill Script Google Spreadsheet Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need you to help me out with this. I need a script on my Google Spreadsheet.

I need the script to do exactly what <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> does.

So it's auto filling the whole page based on the first row.

In terms of details.

Let's say there are two sheets, Sheet1 and Sheet2.

Now Sheet2 is a database. So every cell and row has plain value/text.

In Sheet1 I have the simplest formulas in each cell of row 1.

```
..Column 1....Column 2....Column 3...and so on
=Sheet2!A1, =Sheet2!B1, =Sheet2!C1,
```

So when you select the first row, grab the dot and drag down it will populate formulas into rows bellow and they will be like

```
=Sheet2!A1, =Sheet2!B1, =Sheet2!C1,
=Sheet2!A2, =Sheet2!B2, =Sheet2!C2,
=Sheet2!A3, =Sheet2!B3, =Sheet2!C3,
```

So when you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> it will select the whole Sheet1 then when you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> it will populate the formulas to every row in that worksheet.

**My goal is to get script to be doing this.**

So far I wrote

```
function f5(){
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var allData = sheet.getDataRange();
var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,allData.getNumRows(),7)
range.activate();
};
```

Which selects the desired range but I don't think this is correct way going forward. I also was thinking of keypress simulation but can't get find any documentation saying that this can be done.

Comment: Bump for the time being :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something following should work:

```
  var oneRowCopy = sheet.getRange(1,1,1, sheet.getLastColumn());
  var targetRows = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1, sheet.getLastColumn());
  oneRowCopy.copyTo(targetRows);
```