# SpreadSheet cell auto fill when specific data is inputed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

There exist google script that we can write a function for our spreadsheet.

My question is that I would put data, which is in specific format, to google spreadsheet cell, then I want google Spreadsheet would help me auto complete the cell (prepend "http://test.com").

For example :

I want to put data to some cell like :

> 0BwOZauWX0uR8bWY2d09FV2FaVHc
>
> 9WbOZauWU7uR8bWY8d75FV3FaVKj
>
> other format data

And I hope my google spreadsheet could help me complete the else, namely, make the cell with the specify format like the would become  :

> http://test.com/0BwOZauWX0uR8bWY2d09FV2FaVHc
>
> http://test.com/9WbOZauWU7uR8bWY8d75FV3FaVKj
>
> other format data

I don't want to use the formula because it would waste another cell in the spreadsheet.
So what could I do?
what key word is this and is there an existing google script for me to achieve the goal ?

Comment: very slightly related (10 results found with same tags plus "auto fill"): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16859941/autofill-script-google-spreadsheet-script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a custom script to achieve this by linking it to the `onEdit` event.

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() == "Sheet1" && range.getColumn() == 1 && range.getValue().toString().trim() !== "" && range.getValue().indexOf("http:") != 0) {
    range.setValue("http://test.com/" + range.getValue());
  }
}
```

After this, you need link it to the `onEdit` trigger. **Resources** -> **Current project's triggers**

You can read [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers) to understand triggers. [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FNSj_QNQzSiwoMMhkTb0AO_xAlS5GmzLwowz2O634mA/edit?usp=sharing) is a working copy.

Comment: It seems that if i edit the cell in the second time, it would prepend again. And I want the activeCell must match the format then prepend the texts, is there any judgement i could use ?

Comment: Yeah, I missed that. You could check if the value starts with `http:`

Comment: Good!! And I hope that when I edit the cell again which is prepended, the cell would return back to origin data without the prepended "http://test.com", how would you do that with the script ?

Answer (score 0):

Code from @Konstant works but if you want to use it as Hyperlink change `range.setValue("http://test.com/" + range.getValue());`
to
`range.setValue('=HYPERLINK("http://test.com/' + event.value + '"; + \"' + event.value + '\")');`

And if you want to let this look like a URL add this code below:
 `range.setUnderline(true); range.foregroundColor(blue);`